# IOS: draw a line that remove another line

Tags: ios, xcode, drawing

In my code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
mouseSwiped = YES;

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:drawImage];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), r, g, b, a);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lastPoint = currentPoint;

mouseMoved++;

if (mouseMoved == 10) {
    mouseMoved = 0;
}
}
```

I'm able to draw a line in drawImage, but if I want draw a line that remove the other line? as a eraser that cancel the others line drawn. is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa: How to erase line from image by painting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317152/cocoa-how-to-erase-line-from-image-by-painting)

Comment: yes this link help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863931/want-to-add-manual-erasing-option-in-ipad-painting-application-by-quartz/12797513#comment19041354_12797513

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to "erase" pixels by drawing a line that replaces what's underneath with transparency, then you need to make your stroke colour fully transparent but also change the blend mode to `kCGBlendModeCopy` (with the default blend mode, drawing with a fully transparent stroke colour has of course no effect).

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeCopy);
```

After that, you can draw the "eraser" line just like you are doing in your code snippet (`CGContextMoveToPoint`, `CGContextAddLineToPoint`, `CGContextStrokePath`)